# Sql query to output doesn't contain a specific character from a string

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I want to write an SQL query condition for a data extension field that is a STRING to not pull the ones that have the third and the last letter a specific character.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SUBSTRING` function in your SQL query to extract the third and last letter of the string field and then use the `NOT LIKE` operator to exclude records that have those specific characters. Here's an example of a query that excludes records where the third and last letter of the string_field are 'A':

```
SELECT *
FROM [data_extension]
WHERE 
    (SUBSTRING(string_field, 3, 1) NOT LIKE 'A')
    AND (SUBSTRING(string_field, LEN(string_field), 1) NOT LIKE 'A')
```

You can replace the 'A' with any character you want.